# Sticky nav is displaying above overlay

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical sticky nav on the left side of my page, and a top header with a drop down, when one of the items is dropped down, the stick nav displays on top of the drop down when I have `z-index: 0`, when I change the `z-index: -1` then the nav displays under the dropdown, but the links are no longer clickable.

I have tried changing the `z-index` of `.sub-content` to a very high value and it still displays on top.

What can I do to make it so the sticky nav displays under the overlay and yet still have the items clickable?

This is the related css:

```
nav.right>ul {
  overflow: auto;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 60px;
}
```

Clickable, but displays above the overlay `z-index: 0`:

```css
nav.right>ul {
  overflow: auto;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 60px;
}

a { color: skyblue; }

main {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}

main>nav {
  width: 20%;
}

main {
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.sub-content>div>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sub-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  background: #292929;
  padding: 5vh 0;
}

.sub-content>div:first-child {
  width: 25vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

nav.top>ul>li:hover>.sub-content {
  display: block;
}

.sub-content>div>ul>li>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.sub-content>div>ul>li>a:hover {
  /* background: #ee2012; */
  text-decoration: underline;
}

nav.top {
  background: #f44336;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

nav.top>ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav.top>ul>li>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav.top>ul>li>a:hover,
nav.top>ul>li>a.router-link-exact-active {
  background: #ee2012;
}
```

```html
<nav class="top">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Item</a>
      <div class="sub-content">
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Sub Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <nav class="right">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Not clickable but displays under the overlay `z-index: -1`:

```css
nav.right>ul {
  overflow: auto;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  position: sticky;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 60px;
}

a { color: skyblue; }

main {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}

main>nav {
  width: 20%;
}

main {
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.sub-content>div>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sub-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  background: #292929;
  padding: 5vh 0;
}

.sub-content>div:first-child {
  width: 25vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

nav.top>ul>li:hover>.sub-content {
  display: block;
}

.sub-content>div>ul>li>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.sub-content>div>ul>li>a:hover {
  /* background: #ee2012; */
  text-decoration: underline;
}

nav.top {
  background: #f44336;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

nav.top>ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav.top>ul>li>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav.top>ul>li>a:hover,
nav.top>ul>li>a.router-link-exact-active {
  background: #ee2012;
}
```

```html
<nav class="top">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Item</a>
      <div class="sub-content">
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Sub Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <nav class="right">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Everything seems clickable to me in the example you've provided.

Comment: Yeah, but the left items are above the black drop down (hover over the item in the red top bar) and because `z-index` is set to 0. Changing it to `-1` they are no longer clickable.

Comment: Should be solvable with just the standard z-index, bump `nav.top` up to z-index 2 and it should work

Comment: Even after altering the z-index, I can still click the dropdown links in the example.

Comment: @DBS That works! I didn't think to change the `z-index` of that element